# How to make a row responsive using bootstrap in a react-application?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Whenever I make the size smaller, my **input type text** always goes below when making the screen smaller but my **select** stays on the same row, how to make it so that the the Select Status and my Input search box text stays in same line when making my screen smaller in web page?

**CODE**

```
<div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> 


                  <FormGroup bsSize="large" onChange={this.onChangeSummary.bind(this)} >

                      <div className="selectStatus"> 
                       <div className='col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 clearfix' style={{width: 200}}>
                        <Select
                                value={{label: this.state.statusColor}}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                options={optionsStatus}
                                styles={colourStylesLiveOn}



                         /> 
                      </div>
                     </div>
                       <div className='col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 clearfix' style={{maxWidth: 1700}}>
                         <FormControl style={{maxWidth:1700}} defaultValue={this.state.summaryLiveOn} onBlur={this.onChangeSummary.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder="Summary information" spellcheck="false"/>
                       </div>
                    </FormGroup>

                  </div>

</div>
```

**How I want it to look when resizing to smaller screen size, it looks like this currently on a full size page below:**
[image]

**How it looks like when it is resized to smaller webpage below:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're overwriting the bootstrap css with a hardcoded width value of 200

`<div className='col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 clearfix' style={{width: 200}}>`

Try removing the style property.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I have another question, what if I want to make my Select a bit smaller, but when i use **<div className='col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 clearfix'>** its too small and when i use **<div className='col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 clearfix'>** its too big

Comment: That was why I put width: 200

Comment: what about a `max-width: 200`

Comment: If I put max-width, it doesnt become responsive anymore.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for the help of removing max-width: 200 :D